# Unable to open file located inside subdirectory python

Tags: python, file-handling

I want to read data from specific files from a directory whose structure is as follows:

```
-Directory
  -Subdirectory1
    -AGreek.srt
    -AEnglish.srt
  -Subdirectory2
    -BGreek.srt
    -BEnglish.srt
-test.py
```

Where test.py is my script and I'm supposed to read only the english files from the `Directory`. This is my current script:

```
import os

substring = 'English.srt'

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk('Directory'):
    for filename in files:
        if substring in filename:
            fp = open(os.path.abspath(filename))
            # Further Action
```

However this is giving me the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/coder/Spam/AEnglish.srt'
```

How do I resolve the error? (P.s.: `Spam` is the folder inside which `Directory` and `test.py` are located)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `os.path.join(root,filename)` to access the file.

**Ex:**

```
import os

substring = 'English.srt'

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk('Directory'):
    for filename in files:
        if substring in filename:
            fp = open(os.path.join(root,filename))
            # Further Action
```

Comment: Worked perfect! Btw another question, I want to print out the 3rd,7th,11th,,and so on lines upto the end of file. How do I do this? Logic will be checking if line_no%4==3 but I'm unable to implement it in this code. How do I get the line number and read out that particular line only?I tried using enumerate method but not sure how to execute it properly. Could you please help